# Validation performed on initial form load

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a registration form that a user can access via invitation. For example, an invited user can go to `/users/register/[invite_code]` and get a registration form that is partially populated. I'm seeing something I didn't expect:

If the invite code is valid, we return the user structure and set that in `$this->data` so that the form is automagically pre-populated. The pre-population works, but when the form loads, the data validation errors are displayed as though I'd submitted the form. I see a lot of "[Field name] cannot be empty" when a value has been pre-populated.

In response to questions, the register action is called to both display and submit the form. The code looks like this:

```
public function register( $invite = null ) {
  # Handle a submitted registration
  if( !empty( $this->data ) ) {
    # Do stuff...

    if( $this->User->save( $this->data ) ) {
      $this->Session->setFlash( 'Welcome. Thanks for registering.', null, null, 'success' );
      $this->redirect( $this->Auth->redirect() );
    }
    else {
      $this->Session->setFlash( 'Oh noz. There\'s a problem with your registration.', null, null, 'validation' );
    }
  }

  # If an invite is passed, pull the user attached to that invite.
  if( !empty( $invite ) ) {
    # Attempt to pull the user that owns the invite

    if( empty( $user ) ) { # Unrecognized invite code
      # Do stuff...
    }
    else { # Invited user found
      if( !empty( $user['User']['password'] ) ) { # Invited user has already registered
        # Do stuff...
      }
      else { # This is the invited user
        $this->data = $user;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

After coming back to this, the problem comes when I assign the user to `$this->data`. When I remove that, no validation errors. Unfortunately, no pre-population either. I need the latter, so I need to find a way of setting the data points without triggering the error messages.

**UPDATE 2**

If I dump `$this->User->invalidFields()`, even as early as the first line of `UsersController::beforeFilter()`, the array is populated with invalids. How is this possible? What could I possibly be doing that early in the request to cause this?

**UPDATE 3**

I've also noticed that as I enter `UsersController::beforeFilter()`, the value of `$this->User->id` is already set. I have no idea where or why, but this seems significant. As far as I know, the first step into the actual application code is the relevant controller's `beforeFilter` method and the user id is set on the way in.

Comment: can you show the code? Your data must have been submitted if you have validation error

Comment: Code and some additional findings have been added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller loadModel() function, unfortunately, sets the id property in the model based on the first parameter on your action. That is a big annoyance that was removed in CakePHP 2.0. Nevertheless there is no code that will auto validate your fields after setting an Id, so my guess is that you have a component handling the auto validation or you have some code in your mode that will do it when the model is created.

If you cannot find the code that is auto validating your data, or do not want to change it,  I suggest you override loadModel() in your controller to remove the id assigment, or just use a named parameter for your action.

Comment: Wow, really? That seems crazy, but if setting the id doesn't cause any kind of validation, I guess it's not a problem. What's weird about the apparent "auto-validation" is that I've dropped log prints everywhere that `Model::validates()` is called in core and nothing is written. No idea where this could be happening.

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you initially setting $this->data before $this->Model->save ?

Comment: No. the save only happens if data is submitted in `$this->data`. When first hitting the URL, I never enter that conditional block. See code above.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, I already did that without any problem. If I understand correctly, it's after the last else that the form is displayed. You can check in the controller, if validation already failed when entering the block with this

```
echo debug($this->User->invalidFields() );
```

Comment: Interestingly, the fields are invalid as soon as you enter the `register()` method. Even if I rip out everything else. I didn't expect that so it'll require some digging.

Comment: That's what I've suspected. Isn't there any redirection that could submit the data?

Comment: I don't _think_ so, but those are famous last words... :-)